# How to have slice pulled out but disable further pulled slice changes

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Slice pulling can easily be toggled as all or none. I'm looking for a way to have a slice pulled out, but disallow any further slice pulling.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4zg3hmn8/1/

Adding a listener on `clickSlice` that prevents default, stops propagation, or returns false doesn't work: the clickSlice event is fired before these subordinate events are triggered.

With `clickSlice` listener: http://jsfiddle.net/4zg3hmn8/2/

More digging shows that the event being triggered is `mouseup` which in turn invokes the `clickSlice` method explaining the subordinate event behavior. Unfortunately, adding a listener on `mouseup` had no effect on the chart at all.

With `mouseup` listener: http://jsfiddle.net/4zg3hmn8/3/

The event is added on a private javascript object not a DOM element, so I was unable to figure out a way to remove via Javascript (it is easily removable with Chrome dev tools).

So how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

When `AmCharts.makeChart` is called the config object passed in is used to extend a base, default chart object. Manipulating this, we can pass in a copy of the addEventListener method used in the base object and effectively overwrite it removing the part we don't want:

```
...
"startDuration": 0,
"valueField": "litres",
"titleField": "country",
"pulledField": "isPulled",
"balloon": {
   "fixedPosition": true
},
"addEventListeners": function(a, b) {
   var c = this
   a.mouseover(function(a) {
      c.rollOverSlice(b, !0, a)
   }).mouseout(function(a) {
      c.rollOutSlice(b, a)
   }).touchend(function(a) {
      c.rollOverSlice(b, a)
   }).mouseup(function(a) {
      alert('ah ah ah... didn\'t say the magic word!')
   }).contextmenu(function(a) {
      c.handleRightClick(b, a)
   })
},
...
```

With `mouseup` listener: http://jsfiddle.net/4zg3hmn8/4/

Comment: Overriding internal methods is just asking for random undefined behavior/breakage down the line, especially if the internals get changed to expect something else to happen in the internal `addEventListeners` method that your workaround isn't accounting for.  Check out my example for a safer way to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding undocumented internal methods and events isn't recommended as it can lead to undefined behavior. If you only want to keep just the default slice pulled out, you can use the `clickSlice` event to call `clickSlice` again, cancelling out the user's initial click. You'll need to set a custom property to tell the event to ignore the manual clickSlice call, though:

```
  "listeners": [{
    event: 'clickSlice',
    method: function(e) {
      if (!e.dataItem.ignore) {
        e.dataItem.ignore = true; //prevent infinite loop
        e.chart.clickSlice(e.dataItem.index); //call clickSlice to cancel out the user's click
        e.dataItem.ignore = false; //reset the ignore flag
      }
    },
  }],
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4zg3hmn8/5/

Comment: great point. a little extra overhead to avoid future breakage is a worthwhile trade.